# How to open modal window on button click in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I can not figure out how to get a ui.bootstrap modal window to work with AngularJS. I'm getting the error messagse: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $modalProvider <- $modal <- AdvancedSearchCtrl

Here's the code:

```
(function () {


angular.module('crm.ma')
    .controller('AdvancedSearchCtrl', function ($modal) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.openModal = function () {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'app/components/common/advancedSearchModal.html',
            controller: advancedSearchInstanceCtrl
        });

    };

    });

angular.module('crm.ma').controller('advancedSearchInstanceCtrl', function ($modalInstance) {

    var modal = this;        

    modal.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.close();
    };

});
})();


<div class="row">
<button ng-click="vm.openModal()">Add User</button>
```

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="advancedSearchModal.html">
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3>Text for header</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    Text for body
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="modal.cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

My module code:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var app = angular
    .module('crm.ma',
        [
            'ui.router',
            'ui.bootstrap',
            'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination',
            'toastr',
            'crm.ma.common',
        ]);
 })();
```

Comment: You would need to list `ui.bootstrap` as dependency in your respective module.

Comment: @PSL It is listed as a dependency in the module.  I edited my question to show this.

Comment: Do you have the ui.bootstrap file loaded?

Comment: @Michelem I have the following script tag in my index.html page     <script src="../bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>

Comment: @isherwood I've tried using $uibModal and I can't get it to work either.  But if you could show a code example, I would be happy to try it again.

Comment: @isherwood What syntax do I need to change?

Comment: What version of ui-bootstrap are you using? What version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: @JoseM I'm not exactly sure.  I didn't set up this project.  It was installed using Bower.  How can I tell what version I am using?

Comment: Look in your `bower.json` file

Comment: @JoseM {
    "author": {
        "name": "https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/graphs/contributors"
    },
    "name": "angular-bootstrap",
    "keywords": [
        "angular",
        "angular-ui",
        "bootstrap"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "ignore": [],
    "description": "Native AngularJS (Angular) directives for Bootstrap.",
    "version": "0.13.4",
    "main": ["./ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"],
    "dependencies": {
        "angular": ">=1.3.0"
    }
}

Comment: See it working here: http://plnkr.co/edit/pj7E3P1hQUgyGstuB62y?p=preview

Comment: @JoseM I looked at your plnkr, and it makes sense.  I have the same code you do, but it still doesn't work in my project.  I'm getting the error message Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $modalProvider <- $modal <- AdvancedSearchCtrl

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93508/discussion-between-josem-and-hollyquinn).

Answer (score 0):

Also, you've defined modalInstance  in 'AdvancedSearchCtrl' but haven't called it.

```
modalInstance.result.then(function(x) { do something here} );
```

Comment: Ok so I've got this  modalInstance.result.then(function () {
                
            });  Not real sure what I'm supposed to put in it?

Comment: @JoseM Do you know what the problem is?  I just can not figure this out.